# Concatenating string and integer not throwing error in PyDev

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7, pydev

```
import sys
class test1:
    def __init__(self) :
        print"intialized"

    def yrt(self):
        try:
            name="gokl"
            age="24"
            address="hjk"
            pincode=516101
            #print "My name is %s,and my age is %s, my address is %s and my pincode is " %(name,age,address)
            **print name+pincode**
        except Exception, hj:
            sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gh=test1()
    try:
        gh.yrt()
    except Exception, ex :
        sys.exit(1)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Have you checked the return code from `sys.exit` ?

Comment: return code is one and,prvsly i didnt print the exception..so its not printing..

Comment: It's also worth that using `SystemExit` or `sys.exit()` should really be for something that has enough context of the overall system to be able to decide it's fatal or a valid system response... (ideally main, or as close to it as possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've explicitly caught and silenced the error. If you want it to be thrown, you shouldn't catch it.

Comment: Thanks daniel,its throwing error after removing try and exception